# How to show images in a Listbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show images in the `Listbox` tkinter widget. My code looks like this:

```
mylist = Listbox(self.labelFrame3, yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set, selectmode=SINGLE)
mylist.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=21, columnspan=21, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

img = Image.open('modeldata/photosamples/amanullahattamuhammad2.0.jpg')  # PIL solution
img = img.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # The (250, 250) is (height, width)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

How to print this image in `Listbox`?

Comment: `Listbox` can only contain text items, you can't insert an image into it. You can try using [`ttk.Treeview`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html)

Comment: Somewhat non-intuitively you can put images into `Text` widgets, so you might want to use one of those instead. They can also be scrolled (see [`tkinter.scrolledtext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html)).

Answer (score 3):

As someone mentioned in a comment you can't put images in a `Listbox`, but as I mentioned in another, you could use a `Text` widget instead because you can put images into them. Below is a relatively simple demonstration of how something like that can be done. Its two buttons illustrate how it can display just text or a combination of the two simultaneously. `Text` widget are actually very versatile.

Anyway, since presumably you want a scrollable list, the `Text` subclass named [`tkinter.scrolledtext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) is used instead of plain one to save work. Since it's a subclass, it can do anything its baseclass can do.

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


class App:
    def __init__(self, image_folder_path, image_file_extensions):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.image_folder_path = image_folder_path
        self.image_file_extensions = image_file_extensions
        self.create_widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.list_btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='List Images', command=self.list_images)
        self.list_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.show_btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='Show Images', command=self.show_images)
        self.show_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.text = ScrolledText(self.root, wrap=WORD)
        self.text.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.text.image_filenames = []
        self.text.images = []

    def list_images(self):
        ''' Create and display a list of the images the in folder that have one
            of the specified extensions. '''
        self.text.image_filenames.clear()
        for filepath in Path(self.image_folder_path).iterdir():
            if filepath.suffix in self.image_file_extensions:
                self.text.insert(INSERT, filepath.name+'\n')
                self.text.image_filenames.append(filepath)

    def show_images(self):
        ''' Show the listed image names along with the images themselves. '''
        self.text.delete('1.0', END)  # Clear current contents.
        self.text.images.clear()
        # Display images in Text widget.
        for image_file_path in self.text.image_filenames:
            img = Image.open(image_file_path).resize((64, 64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

            self.text.insert(INSERT, image_file_path.name+'\n')
            self.text.image_create(INSERT, padx=5, pady=5, image=img)
            self.text.images.append(img)  # Keep a reference.
            self.text.insert(INSERT, '\n')


image_folder_path = 'modeldata/photosamples'
image_file_extensions = {'.jpg', '.png'}
App(image_folder_path, image_file_extensions)
```

Here's it running on a folder on my computer with the images shown:

[image: screenshot]